# Find clicked button from form of referrer in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, request

I click a button in `NextPage.aspx` and redirect with `PostBackUrl` to `StartUpPage.aspx`.

The button names start all with "`ctl`". How can I get the button names in the page load of `StartUpPage.aspx`? I know that in `Request.Form["ctl..."]` is the value of the button. But how can I find out which one was the clicked one?

Here is the code how I create the buttons in `NextPage.aspx`:

```
int i = 0;
        foreach (ListItem li in ListItems)
        {
            Button b = new Button();
            b.Text = li.Text;
            b.PostBackUrl = "StartUpPage.aspx";
            b.ID = "ctl" + i;
            PlaceHolderButtons.Controls.Add(b);
            i++;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should declare a public vriable in "NextPage.aspx ". then everytime you create the button, just set the button id to this variable.Then in "StartUpPage.aspx" page, just call the public variable on pageload. Something like this:

### In NextPage.aspx

```
    public string btnID="";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;



        foreach (ListItem li in ListItems)
        {
            Button b = new Button();

            b.Text = li.Text;
            b.PostBackUrl = "StartUpPage.aspx";
            b.ID = "ctl" + i;
            btnID = b.ID;
            PlaceHolderButtons.Controls.Add(b);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

### in StartUpPage.aspx

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      NextPage ob = new NextPage();
      string ID= ob.btnID
    }
```

you will now get the pressed button id in ID variable

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use query string. When you specify the postbackurl of your button control send also the button id along with it. And in your StartUpPage you can find the control of previous page by giving the control id by fetching it from query string.
Here is the Example :

NextPage.aspx :

`int i = 0;
        foreach (ListItem li in ListItems)
        {
            Button b = new Button();
            b.Text = li.Text;
            b.ID = "ctl" + i;
            b.PostBackUrl = "StartUpPage.aspx?id=" + b.ID;

            PlaceHolderButtons.Controls.Add(b);
            i++;
        }`

StartUpPage:

```
 if (PreviousPage != null)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)PreviousPage.FindControl(Request.QueryString["id"]);
        Response.Write(btn.Text);

    }
```